# How to use a directory that contains round brackets in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a batch file in which the 2 first lines read:

```
set DIRwhereRUN=C:\UNIVERSITY\testSTABLEunstable(WITHrandomBED)
PUSHD %DIRwhereRUN%
```

but the batch does not work.

If I create a directory named `testSTABLEunstable_WITHrandomBED` and copy my stuff there everything works smoothly. Is there a way to make it work with the brackets? I don't want to rename for at least 2 reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult - and misleading -  to isolate two lines as you have. There's nothing wrong with those two lines.

The difficulty that you are having is with "block" statements like

```
IF ... (something
   something
   somethinginvolving DIRWHERERUN
   )
```

This is because batch substitutes the value of any `%var%` with its the-current value before executing the command(s) and hence misinterprets the `)` in `%Dirwhererun%` as the closing-parenthesis of the `IF` (or `ELSE` or `FOR`.)

The way to overcome this is to `"escape"` `%dirwhererun%`'s `)` (ie. temporarily suspend its special meaning) - this is done with the caret `^` - which itself is a special character (with the special meaning "the following character is just a character, not a special character".)

So - how to do this?

Here's a demonstration:

@ECHO OFF
    setlocal

```
set "DIRwhereRUN=U:\UNIVERSITY\testSTABLEunstable(WITHrandomBED^)"
SET dir
set DIRwhereRUN=U:\THISWILLBEWRONG(WITHrandomBED^)
SET dir
set DIRwhereRUN=U:\UNIVERSITY\testSTABLEunstable(WITHrandomBED^^)
SET dir
set DIRwhereRUN=U:\UNIVERSITY\testSTABLEunstable(WITHrandomBED)
SET dir
MD %DIRwhereRUN%
PUSHD "%DIRwhereRUN%"
DIR
POPD
SET dirwhererun=%dirwhererun:)=^^)%
SET dir
```

(Note that I use `U:` as a temporary drive. I'm creating the directory using your original `SET` deliberately to show that it's not the `SET` or normal operations that are causing the problem)

Note that where the `set` uses quotes around the parameters, the value is applied literally. This form is often used to ensure that stray trailing spaces in lines are not included in the value set into the variable.

Note that the `^` seems ineffectual in the next `set` - because all it is doing is escaping the `)` - and `)` is NOT a special character in an ordinary `SET`

With the third version, the caret is included - but only one, because `^` escapes `^` and `)` is an ordinary character.

Then we do all of the operations using the `)` unadorned. Obviously attempting to re-create a directory is going to cause an error - but it's because the directory already exists, not because there's anything wrong with the command itself.

As demonstrated, the directory will be listed, so the `PUSHD` works correctly.

Finally, there's a method of setting a variable dynamically - possibly better set into another variable-name. This is useful where the variable may be read from a file or input from a user - that is, not specified literally.

Well - not quite finally. Two further quirks: First, `%` is not escaped by `^` but by `%`, and second, `ECHO(` appears to be the most flexible form of `ECHO` (where the character immediately following `ECHO`, normally space, but may be a number of others) - and doesn't participate in the statement-blocking mechanism.

Comment: Thanks...but I dont get that SET dir... why uppercase...and whats dir... and I guess you forgot all the escape on the first bracket right?

Comment: maybe u meant SET  DIRwhereRUN...but what about the other first bracket?

Comment: There is no need to escape the open parentheses. Batch is largely case-insensitive. My editor automagically upper-cases keywords, but sometimes forgets. The only time in batch that the command `IS` case-sensitive is with a `metavariable` - that is, the loop-control variable in a `FOR` statement. Commands such as `findstr` and `if` `ARE` sensitive to the case of the `DATA` with which they are dealing, but the command itself may be `findstr` `FinDStr` `FINDSTR` - and combination.

Comment: Note that the command `SET DIR` will `SHOW` the value of any variable starting `DIR` - the result of the SET just done. Hence, by running what I've posted, you would be able to see the difference between the various combinations of caret and the use of enclosing quotes in a `set` command.

Answer (score 1):

( and ) are special characters to the shell, so you need to escape them. Cmd.exe's escape character is **^**. So you can do the following:

```
set DIRWHERERUN=C:\UNIVERSITY\testSTABLEunstable^(WITHrandomBED^)
```

Bill

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes.

```
set "DIRwhereRUN=C:\UNIVERSITY\testSTABLEunstable(WITHrandomBED)"
PUSHD "%DIRwhereRUN%"
```